# Generating regex-based string with RandExp

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to generate a string based on regex which would result random letters and numbers, 4 dashes at random places in 36-character string.

Example:

`123A5678-01B3C5F7-901R345-789F1-3456`

I've figured out a regex that seems to validate given string well:

`(?=.{36}$)([0-9A-Z]+-){4}([0-9A-Z])+`

...but using the same for generating string in RandExp ends  up in a mess. It generates 36-character string and adds 5 random-length groups:

`new RandExp(/(?=.{36}$)([0-9A-Z]+-){4}([0-9A-Z])+/).gen()`

`M78QMOC6OGIF5OAJAJCG68CQWJGT5FX43CTKZ9CS9GXWLEKUKZMG602U5HPR4CEKO7OIX45CMLB7DS5RHZBI8KE8HGO9ET6OWS9A-PQSHN9E36KIMW328A1L0BHXCFOJVCD2ZT11-KD03XTZ375WP7CR7YSF4CTSX-0FBJ3MZ4RNDLA5UZOHI5QWVY66PTUDDRCG-OH4F688VM1`

Should I just settle for fixed-width groups for my string using something like:

`([0-9A-Z]{6}-){4}[0-9A-Z]{8}`

... or is there any way I could improve the original regex?

Comment: What does 'generate a string based on regex' mean? Regexen don't generate strings. Take a look at [ask]. Include your code, preferably in a [MCVE].

Comment: @pvg Indeed, regex doesn't create. But he's using [randexp](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js).

Comment: [Randexp](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js) is a JS library that can generate strings matching a certain regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It seems impossible to use a whole string length restricting lookahead with [`Randexp`](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js).** I also tried with your pattern, and it generates a string with *n* chars of any type, like `$>Qa MG4XT@#j{3#&[+V4=^"VQLI*|b%bp~@` (1).

It is even more strange when you apply anchors, `new RandExp(/^(?=.{36}$)(?:[0-9A-Z]+-){4}[0-9A-Z]+$/)` will also produce some ~30 chars of various types at the start of the string. It might be related to the fact that `$` is not used at the final pattern position, and is ignored (see [*Bad Regular Expressions*](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js#bad-regular-expressions)). **It looks like a bug to me**.

Removing the lookahead and adding `^` start-of-string anchor at the start and `$` end-of-string anchor at the end makes it generate somewhat better strings (2). However, you might really want to only use fixed length groups (3).

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "(1)&nbsp;" + new RandExp(/(?=.{36}$)([0-9A-Z]+-){4}([0-9A-Z])+/).gen();
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/><br/>(2)&nbsp;" + new RandExp(/^(?:[0-9A-Z]+-){4}[0-9A-Z]+$/).gen();
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/><br/>(3)&nbsp;" + new RandExp(/^(?:[0-9A-Z]{6}-){4}[0-9A-Z]{8}$/).gen();
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases/download/v0.4.1/randexp.min.js"></script>
```

You may then try to work around that problem by using `/^(?:[0-9A-Z]{6,8}-){4}[0-9A-Z]{6,8}$/` regex in a loop and only return a result if the string is 36 chars long:

```js
var rdx = new RandExp(/^(?:[0-9A-Z]{6,8}-){4}[0-9A-Z]{6,8}$/);
var res = rdx.gen();
while (res.length !== 36) {
    res = rdx.gen();
}
document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases/download/v0.4.1/randexp.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Having [written a very similar library to this myself](https://github.com/tom-lord/regexp-examples), I can say: Look-aheads are not supported by the library because they're "not *really* **regular** expressions". Supporting them would require using a totally different algorithm, and it may not even be 100% possible. In order to achieve what OP originally wanted, I'd recommend e.g. combining `RandExp` with some additional logic -- e.g. generate a 36-char string and only *then* substitute 4 random characters with `-`.

Comment: @TomLord: Yes, there must be some additional logic. I suggested a quick workaround at the bottom of the answer. It's a pity it is not mentioned in the library readme that it is not fully JS regex compatible.

Comment: Also, for anyone wondering, approximately `18.54%` of the time, the above code **will** randomly generate a string of length 36.

Comment: Thanks for the really constructive answer, it confirmed my doubts that look-aheads just won't well for generation. I've decided to keep the complex regex for validation but use the simpler fixed-width regex when generating a string.